# structural induction

Tags: induction

prove by structural induction that in any tree T, the number of leaves is 1 more than the number of nodes that have right siblings.

My proof so far:

s(n).  in any tree T, the number of leaves(L) is 1 more than the number of nodes(N) that have right siblings.

s(1) for a tree of one node, there are no right siblings so n=1. The root itself is a leave so L =1. Thus L=n+1 is true, so the basis is true.

s(n+1)...Im stuck at the induction part here.

Comment: If this is homework, I think you're supposed to mark it as such.  As a preliminary hint, [structural induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) is not mathematical induction.  The second paragraph of that article might help you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of similar things that are called "trees" in graph theory.  I interpret this question to mean full binary trees (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)) -- that is, each non-leaf node has a "left" and a "right" descendant.

*Hint*:  How can you modify a full binary tree with n+1 nodes to a full binary tree with n nodes?  Well, you could try deleting a leaf-node, but then you will end up with a non-leaf node with only one descendant (which isn't a full binary tree).  So this isn't going to work.

So how can you ensure that a full binary tree (with fewer nodes) is constructed?

Answer (score 0):

How do you define a leaf?  The idea of structural induction would be to show that whenever you add a new node to an existing tree, the difference between leaves and nodes without right siblings stays constant.  Without the leaf definition I can't help further.